# Html Webpack Plugin renders JS module instead of HTML file

Tags: javascript, webpack, ejs, html-webpack-plugin

I'm trying to use an EJS loader and the Html Webpack Plugin to compile and output an HTML file but it keeps rendering a file like this:

```
module.exports = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n  <head>\n    <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">\n  </head>\n\n  <body>\n    <div id=\"root\"></div>\n  </body>\n</html>\n"
```

Here's my webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  target: 'node',
  entry: './src/server.tsx',
  output: {
    filename: 'server.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ejs$/, 
        use: {
          loader: 'ejs-webpack-loader',
          options: {
            data: { example: 'test' }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'output.html',
      inject: false,
      template: path.join(rootDir, '../compiler/templates/index.ejs'),
      { example: 'test' },
      minify: false
    })
  ]
}
```

Here's my 'index.ejs' file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <%- include ./test.ejs %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here's my 'test.ejs' file:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

I expect this to output an `output.html` file that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But instead I get this:

```
module.exports = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n  <head>\n    <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">\n  </head>\n\n  <body>\n    <div id=\"root\"></div>\n  </body>\n</html>\n"
```

It looks like the `ejs-webpack-loader` is working and properly injects the partial, but then the HtmlWebpackPlugin is rendering JS instead of HTML.

How do I get the HtmlWebpackPlugin to render the HTML file properly?

Comment: I worked around the problem by tweaking the order of my merged webpack configs - whenever the EJS module rule is in the base config, it doesn't work, but if I move the EJS module rule to the entry config, it works fine.. I can reproduce this behavior in a simple repo if there's any interest in getting to the bottom of it. Seems to be an issue with webpack-merge

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a special loader (ejs-webpack-loader) in your config, since [HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/dfb98e70f813562c007249152ba902e53cbd94e1/docs/template-option.md#1-dont-set-any-loader) comes with ejs support out of the box.

Just try to remove it. :]

Comment: Thanks but HtmlWebpackPlugin doesn't support `include` so I need the EJS loader to compile the partials

Comment: If I try removing the EJS loader I get: `ERROR in Template execution failed: ReferenceError: include is not defined`

Comment: weird, I've linked to the official docs which states that it does (and I know from my personal usage). can you share a small reproduction git repo, I will be able to help more.

Comment: thanks! I reproduced the webpack include issue in a simple environment here: https://github.com/sbiermanlytle/ssr/tree/master/server. I tried reproducing the EJS loader issue too but its working in this repo.. trying to figure out what is different in my main project